# Given $f(x) = \frac1{ax+b}$, for which $a$, $b$ such that $x_1=f(x_3) $, $ x_2=f(x_1) $, $x_3=f(x_2) $ are distinctive

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, rational-functions, fixed-points

For real numbers $a$ and $b$ define

$$f(x) = \frac1{ax+b}$$

For which $a$ and $b$ are there three distinct real numbers $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ such that $f(x_1) = x_2$, $f(x_2) = x_3$ and $f(x_3) = x_1$?

I tried to isolate a/b, and I found 3 values: 
f(x1) = x2 ---> 1/(a.x1 + b) = x2 ---> a.x1.x2 + b.x2 = 1 ---> I f(x2) = x3 ---> 1/(a.x2 + b) = x3 ---> a.x2.x3 + b.x3 = 1 ---> II f(x3) = x1 ---> 1/(a.x3 + b) = x1 ---> a.x1.x3 + b.x1 = 1 ---> III make I=II then, a/b = (x3 - x2)/x2.(x1 - x3) ---> x1 ≠ x3, for example, but i don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I tried to isolate a/b, and I found 3 values:

Comment: f(x1) = x2 ---> 1/(a.x1 + b) = x2 ---> a.x1.x2 + b.x2 = 1 ---> I

f(x2) = x3 ---> 1/(a.x2 + b) = x3 ---> a.x2.x3 + b.x3 = 1 ---> II

f(x3) = x1 ---> 1/(a.x3 + b) = x1 ---> a.x1.x3 + b.x1 = 1 ---> III              make I=II then,   a/b = (x3 - x2)/x2.(x1 - x3) ---> x1 ≠ x3, for example

Comment: (Sorry for multiple edits.)  If you know linear algebra, you can state the problem as follows: find real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\a&b\end{pmatrix}$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $\lambda^3$ is real but $\lambda$ is not real.  (Answer: $a=-b^2\ne0$)

Comment: Nice! But i don't know linear algebra :(

Comment: Can you solve it by "simple" algebra, or something like that, please?

Answer (score 3):

Assume $a\ne 0$. Then, $$x_1 = \frac1{ax_3+b}= \frac1{a\frac1{ax_2+b}+b}=\frac1{a\frac1{a\frac1{ax_1+b}+b}+b}$$

which leads to

$$(a+b^2)(ax_1^2+bx_1-1) = 0\tag 1$$

and similarly,

$$(a+b^2)(ax_2^2+bx_2-1) = 0,\>\>\>\>\>(a+b^2)(ax_3^2+bx_3-1) = 0\tag 2$$

If $a+b^2\ne 0$, then the solutions are

$$x_1 = x_2=x_3=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2+4a}}{2a}$$

and there are no real values of $a$ and $b$ that would make the three $x$'s distinct. On the other hand, if $a+b^2=0$, there are infinite number of solutions to (1) and (2) which can all be distinct. Thus, the values of $a$ and $b$ satisfy

$$a+b^2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a linear algebra approach.  It is long because I am trying to explain what is going on.  However, the approach of pairing a map of the form $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ with the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ is very useful.  For example, if $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ and $\tilde{f}(x)= \frac{\tilde{a}x+\tilde{b}}{\tilde{c}x+\tilde{d}}$ correspond to the matrices $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ and $\tilde{A}=\begin{pmatrix}\tilde{a}&\tilde{b}\\\tilde{c}&\tilde{d}\end{pmatrix}$, respectively, then $f\circ \tilde{f}$ corresponds to the matrix $A\tilde{A}$.

Back to the question, recall that $f(x)=\frac{1}{ax+b}=\frac{0x+1}{ax+b}$.  First of all $a\ne 0$ (otherwise $f$ is constant which obviously doesn't fit the bill).  Let $A$ be the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\a&b\end{pmatrix}$.  The fact that $a\ne 0$ means that $A$ has rank $2$.  Therefore $A$ is invertible (whence the eigenvalues of $A$ are non-zero).

Associate a real number $x$ with any non-zero vector $\xi=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$ s.t. $v\ne 0$ and $\frac{u}{v}=x$.  We use the notation $x\sim\xi$ in this case.   Also associate $\infty$ with vectors $\zeta=\begin{pmatrix}w\\0\end{pmatrix}$ with $w\ne 0$.  (Using $\infty$ is useful here.  We can for example set $f(-b/a)=\infty$ and $f(\infty)=0$.)   Observe that if real numbers $x$ and $y$ satisfy $x\sim\xi$ and $y\sim \xi$
for some non-zero vector $\xi$, then $x=y$.

Suppose that $x\sim \xi$.  Then show that $f(x) \sim A\xi$.  Now let $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ be distinct real numbers s.t. $f(x_1)=x_2$, $f(x_2)=x_3$, and $f(x_3)=x_1$.  If $x_i\sim \xi_i$ for $i=1,2,3$, then $$x_2=f(x_1)\sim A\xi_1.$$  But we have $x_2\sim \xi_2$ also.  By the definition of $\sim$, this means $A\xi_1=r\xi_2$ for some non-zero real number $r$.  Now
$$x_3=f(x_2)\sim A\xi_2$$
and $x_3\sim \xi_3$.  Using the same argument, $A\xi_2=s\xi_3$ for some non-zero real number $s$.  Finally from
$$x_1=f(x_3)\sim A\xi_3$$
and $x_1\sim \xi_1$, we get that $A\xi_3\sim t\xi_1$ for some non-zero real number $t$.

Therefore
$$A^3\xi_1=A^2(A\xi_1)=A^2(r\xi_2)=rA^2\xi_2=rA(A\xi_2)=rA(s\xi_3)=rs(A\xi_3)=rst\xi_1.$$
Therefore $A^3$ has a (non-zero) real eigenvalue $rst$.  Since $A$ is a real $2\times 2$ matrix, either it has two real eigenvalues or two non-real conjugate eigenvalues.  We want to prove that $A$ doesn't have a real eigenvalue.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that both eigenvalues of $A$ are real numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. Note that
$$\det(A^2+kA+k^2I)=(\lambda_1^2+k\lambda_1+k^2)(\lambda_2^2+k\lambda_2+k^2)>0$$
if $k=\sqrt[3]{rst}$.  Hence $(A^2+aA+a^2I)$ is invertible.

Now $$(A^2+kA+k^2I)(A-kI)\xi_1=(A^3-k^3I)\xi_1=A^3\xi_1-k^3\xi_1=A^3\xi_1-rst\xi_1=0.$$
So $$A\xi_1-k\xi_1=(A-kI)\xi_1=(A^2+kA+k^2I)^{-1}0=0.$$  That is $A\xi_1=k\xi_1$.  But we know $A\xi_1=r\xi_2$.  Therefore $k\xi_1=r\xi_2$.  That means $x_1$ and $x_2$ are associated to $\xi_2$.  This shows that $x_1=x_2$, contradicting the assumption that $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are distinct.  Hence the eigenvalues of $A$ must be non-real complex numbers $\lambda$ and $\bar{\lambda}$.

Now $rst$ is an eigenvalue of $A^3$, so we must have $\lambda^3=k^3$ or $\bar{\lambda}^3=k^3$ (recalling that $k^3=rst$ is real).  In the latter case, $\lambda^3=\overline{\left(\bar{\lambda}^3\right)}=\overline{k^3}=k^3$, so we still have $\lambda^3=k^3$ anyhow.  Therefore, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ which is non-real but $\lambda^3$ is the real number $k^3$.  Since $\lambda$ is non-real, $\lambda\ne k$, so
$$\lambda^2+k\lambda+k^2=\frac{\lambda^3-k^3}{\lambda-k}=0.$$
This shows that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$\det(A-qI)=q^2+kq+k^2.$$
But $$\det(A-qI)=\det\begin{pmatrix}-q&1\\a&b-q\end{pmatrix}=q^2-bq-a.$$
Therefore $-b=k$ and $-a=k^2$, so
$$a=-k^2=-(-k)^2=-b^2.$$
And we recall that $a\ne 0$, so the necessary condition is $a=-b^2\ne 0$.  This condition is also sufficient because when $a=-b^2\ne0$,
$$A^3=-b^3I.$$
This means that $f\circ f\circ f$ is the identity.  Since $A$ has no real eigenvalue, $f$ has no fixed point.  Consequently, for any $x\in \Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}$, the values of $x$, $f(x)$, and $f\circ f(x)$ are distinct, and $f\circ f\circ f(x)=x$.