# Prove that if $a^2+bc \neq 0$, then the graph of $f(x)= \frac{ax+b}{cx-a}$ is symmetric about the line y=x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, symmetry

> Prove that if $a^2+bc \ne 0$, then the graph of $f(x)= \frac{ax+b}{cx-a}$ is symmetric about the line $y=x$.

Maybe this is a simple exercise, but I need help from you guys to understand how is the best way to solve this problem.

Reversing the coordinates of a point on the graph of $f(x)$ produce a point in the graph of $f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: If we render thevrelation as $(cx-a)y=(ax+b)$, then the condition $a^2+bc\ne 0$ can be dropped. We get a horizontal line and a vertical line when$a^2+bc=0$, a hyperbola having those lines as asymptotes otherwise.

Comment: For a linear algebra proof, let $M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{pmatrix}$.  Then, $M^2$ is a non-zero scalar matrix.  This means $f\big(f(x)\big)=x$ for all $x\neq a/c$.  The converse also holds: if $f(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ with $ad-bc\neq 0$ is symmetric about the line $y=x$, then $d=-a$.  (See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3561155/given-fx-frac1axb-for-which-a-b-such-that-x-1-fx-3-x-2-f/3568509#3568509) for justification.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a different proof:

$$f(f(x))=\frac{af(x)+b}{cf(x)-a}=\frac{a\frac{ax+b}{cx-a}+b}{c\frac{ax+b}{cx-a}-a} =
\frac{\frac{a^2x+ab+bcx-ab}{cx-a}}{\frac{cax+cb-acx+a^2}{cx-a}}= \frac{a^2x+bcx}{cb+a^2}=x$$

So $f(x)$ is its own inverse and so its graph is symmetric respect to $y=x$ (recall that the graph of a function and its inverse are symmetric respect to $y=x$)

Answer (score 0):

A function is symmetric about $y = x$ if $f(\lambda) = \mu \iff f(\mu) = \lambda$ holds for all $\mu, \lambda \in \mathbb R$.

We have
\begin{align}
f(\lambda) = \mu
& \iff \frac{a \mu  + b}{c \mu - a} = \lambda
\iff a \mu  + b = \lambda c \mu - \lambda a
\iff (a - \lambda c) \mu  = - \lambda a - b \\
& \iff \mu =  \frac{- \lambda a - b}{a - \lambda c}
= \frac{\lambda a + b}{\lambda c - a}
= f(\lambda).
\end{align}
The condition $-a^2 \ne bc$ ($\star$) is relevant as in this case we have
$$
f(x)
= \frac{a x + b}{c x - a}
= \frac{b a x + b^2}{bc x - ab}
\overset{(\star)}{=} \frac{b (a x + b)}{-a(ax + b)}
= - \frac{b}{a},
$$
which is constant and thus not symmetrical about $y = x$.